# centering div horizontally

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

My page layout:

```
div for header : position: fixed
div for sidebar: float: left              div for content: float:left
div for footer : position: fixed
```

the positions are set to be like so so that the footer and header are always visible no matter what point in the scroll bar the user is at. The sidebar however scrolls with the page.

the div for content contains a ui:insert so all the pages load in there.
now in one of the pages i want the content to be centered within the space allocated.
all the content of that page is placed in a div for this purpose.
What style do i have to use for the contents to always be centred horizontally no matter what size the window is stretched to. I can specify a fixed value for width of the div.

I cannot set the position to be absolute or fixed as it would ruin the design overall.

Comment: Please post actual code and maybe a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @isherwood Funny you said that: JSFiddle's down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed width:

```
div.center {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For dynamic width:

```
div.center {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 25%;
}
```

JSFiddle isn't working, but I'll get one up ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, the following should do the trick if the width of the div is specified

```
div {margin: 0 auto;}
```